# Connecting to a cloned EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to clone an EC2 instance so that I can test some things. I created an AMI and launched an instance and it seems to be running ok. However, I cannot connect to it with ssh or putty.

My live instance, which I'm making the copy of, has various users who can all log in happily with their private key. But they cannot log in with the exact same credentials to the cloned instance. I just get:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Is there more to do than to just change the IP address from the live instance to the cloned instance?

I also cannot connect to the ec2-user login, using the private key I created during launch. One slight quirk of my live server is that I had to change the AuthorizedKeysFile setting in /etc/ssh/sshd_config in order to deal with some SFTP problems I was having. Is this likely to have messed up the connection for a cloned server? Surely all the settings are identical?

Comment: Is the new instance in a Security Group that has port 22 open?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same security group for both instances.

Comment: How did you 'clone' the instance? Also, when you say "using the private key I created during launch", are you referring to the launch of the original instance or the clone? Have you tried using the keypair that works with the original instance AND the one used when launching the clone? What does `ssh -v` display?

Comment: I created an AMI from a snapshot and launched a new instance from that. As I understand it, the two instances should be identical apart from the IP address? I was referring to the keypair for the new instance. I have tried the keypairs that work with the original instance and they don't work either. Not sure what you mean by ssh -v? I can't log in to the server so I can't run any commands on there to check.

Comment: `ssh -v` is a command you would run locally, to try to connect to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the help, folks. I found the answer, as you can see below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to do with the AuthorizedKeysFile setting after all. I undid the edit I made in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, took another snapshot, made another AMI, launched another instance and all was well. I didn't even need to restart the sshd service, so this didn't mess up my configuration on my live server.

I'm not entirely sure why this caused a problem, but the lesson here is that EC2 needs the AuthorizedKeysFile to be set to the default location or I guess it doesn't know where to look for the public key.